# How to use addEventListener within an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use **addEventListener** within an javascript object and my code is not correct.  To be honest, I'm not entirely sure how to code this correctly. As it stands, 'button1' is not recognised when i try to define the addEventListener.  Please could someone advise?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> </title>
        <style>
            #wrap{
            margin-top: 30px;
            margin-left: 30px;
            }
            .btn{
            font-size: 20px;
            width: 65px;
            height: 45px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrap">
            <button id="btn1"  class="btn">btn1</button>
            <button id="btn2" onclick="pub.moveRight('btn2','60px')" class="btn">btn2</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="test40.js"></script>
</html>
```

My **JS**:

```
var pub = {
    button1: function () {
        return document.getElementById('btn1');
    },

    btn1EventHandler: function () {
        button1.addEventListener('click', function () {
            changeColor('btn1', '#33FFFF');
        });

    }(),

    changeColor: function (id, color) {
        var element = document.getElementById(id);
        element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    },

    name: 'smith',
    moveRight: function (id, pixels) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(id);
        ele.style.marginLeft = pixels;
    }
};
```

Comment: @MuhammadUsman - Obviously, you didn't try it. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'button1' of undefined - line 7 test40.js`

Comment: Why are you invoking the `btn1EventHandler` with `()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actual code `button1` is just a function, and you can't add event listener on a function.

You should call this function and store its result on an object, then you will be able to `addEvenetListener`on it, for example:

**EDIT:**

I recommend that you declare your `pub` object as a *module* and then give it its attributes and functions.

This is a demo snippet:

```js
pub = function() {
  this.button1 = function button1() {
      return document.getElementById('btn1');
    },
    this.btn1 = this.button1(),
    this.btn1EventHandler = function() {
      btn1.addEventListener('click', function() {
        changeColor('btn1', '#33FFFF');
      });

    }(),

    this.changeColor = function(id, color) {
      var element = document.getElementById(id);
      element.style.backgroundColor = color;
    },

    this.name = 'smith',
    this.moveRight = function(id, pixels) {
      var ele = document.getElementById(id);
      ele.style.marginLeft = pixels;
    }
};
```

```css
#wrap {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 65px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <button id="btn1" class="btn">btn1</button>
  <button id="btn2" onclick="new pub().moveRight('btn2','60px')" class="btn">btn2</button>
</div>
```

And it will work perfectly.

Comment: Could you show me how to incorporate the event listener into the object please?  Would it go under another variable in the object? I think that is now where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Please, take a look at my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

While using objects and accessing the inner properties among themselves use `this`
so for accessing use this

```
     btn1EventHandler: function(){
this.button1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.changeColor('btn1', '#33FFFF');
});

 }(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `button1` is a function. Hence you have to call it to get the element corresponding to the id. Or, declare like this :

```
button1: document.getElementById('btn1')
```

Now, `pub.button1` refers to the button by id `btn1`. You could also use the revealing module pattern to reveal only the public interface and hide the rest of it.

Answer (score 0):

It is good style to **separate** JavaScript and HTML. In an object, first get the elements:

```
var obj = {
    btn1: document.getElementById("btn1"),
    btn2: document.getElementById("btn2"),
    ...
}
```

Then the functions that should do something:

```
var obj = {
    btn1: document.getElementById("btn1"),
    btn2: document.getElementById("btn2"),
    ...
    changeBgColor: function(id, bgColor) { ... },
    moveRight: function(id, width) { ... },
    ...
}
```

And at last add the click event to the specific button with **this**. *This* refers to the variable **within**.

```
var obj = {
    btn1: document.getElementById("btn1"),
    btn2: document.getElementById("btn2"),
    ...
    changeBgColor: function(id, bgColor) { ... },
    moveRight: function(id, width) { ... },
    ...
    addEvent: function() {
        this.btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
            obj.moveRight(...);
        });
    }
}    

obj.addEvent();
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wdzj2bfe/2/)